# selenium webdriver - enabling javascript takes too much time to navigate to URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, htmlunit

I am using Selenium Web driver for navigating to a page. I am using HtmlUnitDriver for headless testing (without a GUI). Here is my simple code:

```
/*
 * Create web driver object
 */
WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(){
        //@override
        protected WebClient getWebClient() {
            WebClient webClient = super.getWebClient();
            //webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
            //webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); //ignore ssl certificate
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
            //webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);
            return webClient;
        }
    };
```

Now I am navigating to a page - http://google.com

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
webDriver.get("http://google.com");
long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Result:: Title: "+webDriver.getTitle()+" Current URL: "+webDriver.getCurrentUrl()+" Time taken(ms): "+timeTaken);
```

I see time taken to navigate to above url is ~3 seconds

If JavaScript is disabled as `webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`, it takes about ~1 seconds

And also on my browser with javascript enabled, when I navigate to http://google.com without any previous cache, it takes about ~1 seconds.

Now my question is why enabling javascript in the code is taking extra time and what code change I need to do to remove this extra time keeping javascript enabled. This happening with other site as well.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is enabled, HtmlUnit will process all the javascript on the page like every browser does. And this requires time. At least at pages doing a lot of javascript the processing might be slower as a modern browser.

Disabling javascript might lead to a not (completely) working page because all the web designers/developers out there believe Javascript is available in every browser and all the fancy effects (and all the user tracking as well) is done using javascript.

Comment: I agree. But there should be not much difference in time taken to process. If an actual browser takes about 1-2 sec to load then selenium web driver should also take something similar time. If you take other site such as http://ndtv.com, you will see difference in time taken to be around 20-30 seconds (actual browser takes 15 sec where as selenium web driver takes 45 sec)

Comment: Yes better performance is always a good thing. If you have time you are welcome to profile the javascript execution and provide patches to make the javascript engine faster.